# What is the difference between "deserves" and "deserved"?

Tags: meaning, tense, verbs

> **deserve** /dəˈzərv/ *verb*
>
> do something or have or show qualities worthy of (reward or punishment).

Which of the following sentences grammatically correct?

> He ***deserved*** to die.

or,

> He ***deserves*** to die.

or maybe they mean the same thing?

Comment: Same essential meaning, but different tenses.

Comment: So you mean, after he died, I would say, "He _**deserved**_ to die."

same goes here:

before he dies, I would say, "He _**deserves**_ to die."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.He deserves to die.
>
> 2.He deserved to die.

Both sentences are grammatical but are used in different contexts. #1 reveals one's opinion with respect to a person's fate, that is to happen sooner or later, whereas #2 talks about one's opinion about a deceased person or one person that somehow escaped death.